# Hacer mi servidor accesible mediante internet

Tags: http, servidor, router

He creado un servidor muy básico y lo he abierto al puerto 80. Luego de ver que funcionaba he decidido hacerlo accesible mediante internet.

Para ello he abierto el puerto 80 del router en la direccion ip de mi ordinador y también he abierto el puerto en mi cortafuegos tanto de entrada como de salida. Aún y así no me deja conectarme desde otro dispositivo que no sea mi ordenador.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

El código de conexión del servidor es éste:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = ('**La ip de mi ordenador**', 80)  # Serve on all addresses, port 80.
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, HelloHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

En el router tengo abierto el puerto 80 en TCP y UDP y en el cortafuegos tengo cuatro reglas que permiten la entrada y salida de UDP y TCP en el puerto 80.

Comment: Puede haber muchas razones para esto.. desde configuración del servidor, a configuración del router e incluso limitaciones del ISP.

Comment: Bueno, tengo el servidor funcionando en el puerto 80 y éste mismo es el que he abierto en el router y el cortafuegos, ahora lo edito con imagenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes un proveedor de servicios de internet que te asigna una IP real(Telmex en México por ejemplo) y no una Nateada, como por ejemplo lo hace TotalPlay aquí en México, deberás realizar el redireccionamiento de puertos en tu router dependiendo de la marca, tendrás que agregar la regla de redireccionamiento de todas las peticiones del puerto 80 a la ip local de tu servidor, igual al puerto 80.

Para saber si tu servidor esta configurado adecuadamente, podrás hacer la prueba desde tu red interna; desde otro dispositivo conectado a la misma red, al acceder a la ip de tu servidor.

Espero haber respondido tus dudas, pero sin más detalles no puedo ayudar más.